# Distinction between acquiring and obtaining

Tags: word-choice, difference

I can't decide between those two words.

> You need to **acquire** handling instructions.
>   You need to **obtain** handling instructions.

Both mean roughly the same, describing an act of gaining possession of something. In my mind, there might be a distinction in how active/passive the recipient is expected to be. However, I can't tell which one, if any, would be more *go-getty* and which would lean towards *bestowy-upony*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you say: acquire or obtain business?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/124359/can-you-say-acquire-or-obtain-business) Also [A comparison between the verbs: “attain, ”achieve“, obtain”, “acquire” and “gain”.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122399/a-comparison-between-the-verbs-attain-achieve-obtain-acquire-and-gain) Sometimes ***acquire*** carries stronger connotations of ***by stealth*** or other unconventional / dishonourable methods, but that's not a hard-and-fast distinction.

Comment: See the article "get" on p. 372 of [_Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms_](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Merriam_Webster_s_Dictionary_of_Synonyms/8N4UReTJYhUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA372#v=onepage&q=acquire%20obtain)—a great resource for these kinds of word choices.

Comment: @Konrad. Where are you based - M-W has a rather strong bias towards US usage...

Comment: @BenKovitz: Indeed. I see MW say "acquire" *may suggest **devious** acquisition* - which agrees with my ***by stealth*** comment. But any such distinction won't always apply, and there's plenty of scope for that nuance to be either intended or not by a speaker, AND understood or not by a listener. So *on average*, learners would probably be better off assuming they really are "the same" - if they want to be sure of conveying this optional nuance of difference, it would be better to do it ***explicitly*** (using more and/or clearer words).

Comment: I might **acquire** something by accident, or incidentally, whereas I **obtain** something deliberately. And I might acquire a suntan, but I would not say "I obtained a suntan." I agree there is a difference. Apart from the dubious angle commented about **acquire**, the **obtain** word is more overt and go-getty.

Comment: ..."I acquired some instructions" suggests they are something you are not supposed to have.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Indeed, the article begins by saying that all the words listed there "are comparable and often interchangeable when they mean to come into possession of." The whole book is about nuance. Yes, the word should be chosen to _reflect_ or "agree with" something else in the context. A good answer should explain this. Good luck to whoever tries to write it!

Comment: @MikeBrockington I'm based in Stockholm but most of my contacts are Americans and Canadians.

Comment: @WeatherVane That should go as the correct answer to be accepted. Could you post it, please?

Comment: Thank you but it would require a lot of research to support my contrasting opinion as a formal answer. Note the remark from @BenKovitz!

Answer (score 0):

I expect that every answer you get will suggest a different degree of stress for each, and fractionally different connotations, but I also suspect that they will average out, with roughly 50% saying that 'acquire' is stronger than 'obtain', and vice-versa, possibly with some degree of regional variation.

'Acquire' is often used in the context of 'theft', but it is also used so frequently without that connotation that I don't think you should worry about that unduly.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This seems to me to be a perfectly reasonable answer—maybe the wisest possible answer, since it steers the OP away from putting more thought into this word choice than it needs.

Comment: Interesting with the downvotes. I have **not** downvoted, for the record. In fact, I find your reply clear and likely to be true. So I'll +1 you in a jiffy. That being said, what do **you** think in the regard of strength of those two?

Comment: I think that someone simply had a bad day. Clicking downvote, kicking a dog... Stuff like that happen to the best of us, sadly. The question was marked as a dupe but the other question has nothing to do with mine at all, accept coincidental term choice. Just a bad day. Luckily, I'm not easily offended. (If one is easily offended, Internet is not for them.)